# Facebook api - check if post to embed has been removed or the privacy settings have been changed

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm currently pulling in reviews via the /{page-id}/ratings endpoint that facebook's graph api provides. From here I get the id of the user that made the review, and also the post id by adding the query parameter "fields=open_graph_story" to the query string. After this I build the fully qualified url's to embed the post. As you can see below certain reviews display fine but others can't since they're no longer available due to being removed or their privacy settings having been changed. My question is how can I determinate if a post is "no longer available" using facebook's graph api so that I can filter out those posts which won't display properly. The endpoints discussed earlier are of no use since that information isn't available. Thanks for any help!

https://i.stack.imgur.com/GkYB4.png

Comment: You can't, really ... Even public posts made by users can only be read by your app, if the user logged in to your app, and granted it permission to read their posts in the first place. _Then_ you could read post properties, such as the used privacy setting. But you're hardly gonna get all people who review a page to do that, I suppose.

Comment: Cheers CBroe :)